# Setting text to name of sound file

Tags: button, audio, settext

I have an app which plays a random sound from my raw folder on the clicking of a button. It works fine, but my attempt to set the text on the button as the next file name fails. Am I far off?
Also, how would I play through the files in order rather than randomly? Thanks, please be gentle.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        final int[] btns = new int[]{R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, R.raw.sound3, R.raw.sound4, R.raw.sound5, R.raw.sound6, R.raw.sound7, R.raw.sound8, R.raw.sound9, R.raw.sound10, R.raw.sound11, R.raw.sound12, R.raw.sound13, R.raw.sound14, R.raw.sound15, R.raw.sound16, R.raw.sound17, R.raw.sound18, R.raw.sound19, R.raw.sound20, R.raw.sound21, R.raw.sound22, R.raw.sound23, R.raw.sound24, R.raw.sound25, R.raw.sound26, R.raw.sound27, R.raw.sound28, R.raw.sound29, R.raw.sound30, R.raw.sound31, R.raw.sound32, R.raw.sound33, R.raw.sound34, R.raw.sound35, R.raw.sound36, R.raw.sound37, R.raw.sound38, R.raw.sound39, R.raw.sound40, R.raw.sound41, R.raw.sound42, R.raw.sound43, R.raw.sound44, R.raw.sound45, R.raw.sound46, R.raw.sound47, R.raw.sound48, R.raw.sound49, R.raw.sound50 };

        private Random rnd = new Random();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((Button) v).setText(rnd);
            int sndToPlay = rnd.nextInt(btns.length);
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.createMainActivity.this, btns[sndToPlay]);
            mp.start();
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your code was a little bit off, but here is the updated function. You were trying to pass in the random object instead of passing in the sound file name.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  int sndToPlay = rnd.nextInt(btns.length);
  ((Button) v).setText(sndToPlay);
  final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.createMainActivity(btns[sndToPlay]);
  mp.start();
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. It doesn't work for me though. I can set the text of the button to a string using that rearrangement of code, but it crashes with passing sndToPlay in. hmmm...

Comment: Should it use a valueOf() method?